# JS RegExp: how to match "for (...)" but not "for...of" or "for...in"

Tags: javascript, regex, for-loop

Can anyone guide me in the right direction for a regexp that will successfully match a standard `for` loop, but not the `for...of` and `for...in` variations? Any help would be so very appreciated.

The backstory & what I've tried so far (and sorry in advance for the long question): I have a coding app written in JavaScript and I currently have a need to find out when the user's code contains loops, however, I need to distinguish between `for` and `for...of` and `for...in`. My original RegExp did not take this into account. I had:

```
// match any loop
const re = new RegExp(/(?:\bwhile|\bfor)\s*?\(.*?\)/)
```

which seemed to do the trick for my purposes, until I realized that this was also matching `for...of` and `for...in` (if you're interested in why I need this, see very bottom).

So I've been trying to write a regexp that will work, but can't seem to get it. Consider the following mock code snippets with loops:

```
const loop1 = `
for (var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {

}`

const loop2 = `
for (var i of arr) {

}`

const loop3 = `
for (var i in arr) {

}`
```

I can write a regexp that can tell when a loop ***is*** a `for...in` or `for...of` loop, but not when one ***is not***

For example, using the above loop snippets:

```
const IS_FOR_OF = new RegExp(/(?:\bwhile|\bfor)\s*?\(.*?(?:\bof\b|\bin\b).*?\)/)


IS_FOR_OF.test(loop1) // false
IS_FOR_OF.test(loop2) // true
```

But when I try to do the opposite, i.e. match open parens, then match any char 0 or more times only if not followed by `of` or `in`, it does not work:

```
const IS_NOT_FOR_OF = new RegExp(/(?:\bwhile|\bfor)\s*?\(.*?(?!\bof\b|\bin\b).*?\)/)

console.log(IS_NOT_FOR_OF.test(loop1)) // true
console.log(IS_NOT_FOR_OF.test(loop2)) // true
```

Thanks!

p.s. the purpose is to apply loop-protection only when the code actually contains loops that could potentially be infinite - applying loop protect to code that does not have loops, or that has loops like `for...of` and `for...in` causes issues, hence this need

Comment: Matching a `for` statement of any kind purely with a RegExp is impossible to do for all cases: `for (var i = (((((((0))))))); ;)`, `for (var { prop = (((((((0))))))) } in array)`, etc.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts while true, in all fairness if your for loops look like that you're probably a psychopath lol

Comment: @SterlingArcher `for (const x of {*[Symbol.iterator]() { let i=0; while(true) yield i++; }})`. Now match that (and don't call me a psychopath either) :D

Comment: @Bergi I meant the massive use of parenthesis :P Never said he was wrong!

Comment: @SterlingArcher I'm not a psychopath, I'm just superstitious! If I don't wrap every expression in my code with 7 parentheses, a terrible curse will befall my family!

Comment: You must have a background in Lisp ;)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts why is it impossible? `/(?:\bwhile|\bfor)\s*?\(.*?\)/` seems to work for me in matching `for` statements. I can see it being problematic if code isn't properly spaced, e.g. `'for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ {} myfunc()'` this still matches even though the loop is unclosed. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @no_stack_dub_sack consider Bergi's example above. You can hypothetically nest an entire program's worth of code inside of one `for` statement. Regular expressions (at least the JavaScript flavor) do not handle arbitrary depth recursion, they're made to parse sequential formats. There are plenty of white papers and various discussions available online supporting this assertion, so just use an existing parser as recommended in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48919793/1541563) below.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thanks for the additional explanation. I see now, and understand where I was going wrong (and that this never would have worked). In the end, the problem was unrelated to the babel transform itself, and was really just me overlooking something silly and creating a ton of extra work for myself. Either way, opening this topic led me to the answer and a less hacky but still probably poor program :-)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this with regular expression. They cannot correctly match arbitrarily nested javascript expressions. Use a proper JS parser instead, and then manipulate the AST.

> The purpose is to apply loop-protection only when the code actually contains loops that could potentially be infinite

You're mistaken in that `for … in` and `for … of` loops cannot possibly be infinite.

Comment: I upvoted because this is true, but is kind of a non-answer without a link to any further resources. ([Hint](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babylon))

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Does [this](https://www.google.com?q=javascript+parser) count as a resource? I didn't want to link any particular one, there are many (esprima, acorn, babylon, …)

Comment: @Bergi > You're mistaken in that for … in and for … of loops cannot possibly be infinite. I didn't necessarily mean that, though I guess it was sort of implied. However, the [loop-protect babel transform](https://github.com/jsbin/loop-protect) I'm using seems to think that they can't be, because it does not transform `for...in` and `for...of`, which is a bummer. If it did, I wouldn't be having this problem. Unfortunately, this is probably beyond my current abilities: > Use a proper JS parser instead, and then manipulate the AST.

Comment: @Bergi can you elaborate on this at all? > Use a proper JS parser instead, and then manipulate the AST.

Comment: @no_stack_dub_sack If you are using babel transforms, you *are* already using a parser: babel. It allows you to *transform* the AST. Get into the details of `loop-protect` and see how you can adjust it to meet your needs.

Comment: @no_stack_dub_sack note that your transform clearly states `Note that this does not solve the halting problem`, implying it simply inserts a termination condition in _every_ loop, to my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers to this question. It led me to reexamine the root of the problem which was that applying loop protect to code that didn't have loops was causing issues. After revisiting it, I was able to solve the root problem (after not being able to for several weeks), so appreciate the push in the right direction.

Comment: You solved the halting problem in only a few weeks!?

Comment: Not that problem :-)